# C DLL with C# exception error (Access Violation)

Tags: c#, c

I have a C DLL that I am call from C#

C Code

```
// The real DLL entry point
__declspec(dllexport) int  Do_7plus(char *cmd_line)
char *p1, *p2;
char **argv;
int argc = 0;
int i, l;
int ret;

/*
    * Count the args.
*/
l = strlen(cmd_line);
```

C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;     // DLL support

namespace Packet
{

public partial class _7PlusFrm : Form
{
[DllImport("7plus.dll")]
public static extern void Do_7plus(string args);
    public _7PlusFrm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Do_7plus("c:\\temp\\7plus.zip -SAVE \"c:\\temp\\\" -SB 5000");
    }
}
}
```

I get an exception error (Access Violation)

How do I fix it?

Is the problem the pointer in C and string in C#?

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but I see an error.  There is one directory separator you forgot to escape: `c:\temp`   (There is only one backslash)

Comment: same error did not help

Comment: Double check the calling conventions! Also, try explicitly specifying the [string marshalling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s97shtze.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [marshal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s97shtze.aspx) the string to the c-string type.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
[DllImport("7plus.dll", Charset = Charset.Ansi)]
public static extern void Do_7plus([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LCPStr)]string args);
```

b.t.w. you can solve this problem without PInvoke and without the massive security vulnerability of that shell injection you are doing.

Comment: Same Error  as before, what is the better way?

Comment: If you have the same error as before, the problem isn't your PInvoke code, it's in the c-code.

Comment: @NA7KR The better way is to use .NET's built in way to invoke another process. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @NA7KR, ah! I bet I know the problem. Updating my answer.

Comment: @NA7KR Try clarifying charset and using LPCSTR, I think you are passing wchar strings and that's whats breaking it.